# Does the NPM package crypto-js relate to cryptocurrency or cryptography?

Tags: npm, cryptography, cryptocurrency

I'm watching a football game @ https://watch.foxtel.com.au/ and I saw in the inspector the site loads the file:

https://watch.foxtel.com.au/app/static/js/npm.crypto-js.7f96017841bd7fff1e02.chunk.js

I think this relates to https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Does that NPM package relate to cryptocurrency or cryptography?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`crypto.js` is purely a cryptography library, without a focus on cryptocurrency specifically.

Looking at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), indeed `crypto.js` does support `ECDSA` over `secp256k1`, and `SHA256`, the primary **cryptographic** **primitives** used in most Bitcoin derived cryptocurrencies.

I guess technically you could leverage its `hashing` functions to mine, and its `ECDSA` signature functions to create BTC transactions, but it certainly wouldn't be a library I would use writing an attack like that, there are many other libraries much better suited.

If you used `crypto.js` for cryptocurrency related work, one would have to build out all of the *cryptocurrency* *specific* stuff from first principles, (e.g. conversion of elliptic curve points (after scalar multiplication) to valid public keys, and on to `base58` encoded Bitcoin addresses, etc).

It's much more likely it was used to leverage a cryptographic primitive for authentication or equivalent.

#### Update:

This actually just looks like the crypto module from Node, thus definitely not cryptocurrency related.

Comment: I don't think that the OP refers to the [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module of NodeJS, but rather to the [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) library, which only supports symmetric, but not asymmetric encryption.